# Showing an Error Provider on a text box when a users tabs out of the text box without entering any data

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, errorprovider

I know this is pretty basic, but I cant get this to work for the life of me.

I have a text box (PassportField) and a check box (PassportCheckBox) that are bound to my class's (Person) properties. The Person class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged and the IDataErrorProvider interfaces.

Here is my Bind controls Source Code:

```
Private WithEvents _PersonBindingSource As New Windows.Forms.BindingSource

Public Sub InitialiseBinding(ByVal person As Person)

  Me._PersonBindingSource.DataSource = person
  Me.PassportCheckBox.DataBindings.Add("Checked", _DoctorClinicBindingSource, "Passport", True,  Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
  Me.PassportField.DataBindings.Add("Text", _DoctorClinicBindingSource, "PassportText", True, Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, String.Empty)

 End Sub
```

I need to validate my text box such that, if the check box is checked, the text box cannot be left blank, and this is indicated by way of an Error provider against the text box.

So if a user checks the check box, and simply tabs out of the text box without entering any data (i.e leaves it blank), the INotifyPropertyChanged should be fired (I know this is probably not going to work because the property 
does not really change)

At the moment the validation is in my business object.

Can someone throw some light on this please?

Comment: On click of check box you just focus your Text box. If the the Text box got focus then the User need to Enter data. if user did't text box will get lost focus, then there itself you can show some alert or message.

Comment: Is Dynamically created controls or normal win forms controls...? have u tried any events something like `_LostFocus` or `_CheckedChanged`

Comment: Hey RJK, thanks for your answer. Its a normal windows forms text box. I am aware that i can do it on the lost focus or better still the OnValidating of the control. But its a bound control and I have the ErrorProvider, and the NotifyOnPropertyChanged mechanism in place. So was wondering if i could exploit that. The error provider works fine, if say there was text in the text box and i cleared it.It fails (rather it does not raise a notification, if if the state of the data hasn't changed.)

Comment: Hi Laavanya.. ok.. How you are calling the notification, i mean Error provider and when.? which event is used to trigger this..?  post some sample code to better understand. Say If you are clearing the text box its not raising the notification In this case event itself its not triggering right...?  :)

Comment: You have a event 'Validating' which is a `CancelEventHandler` and you can cancel the focus change. Put validation logic on both `Validating` and check box's `CheckedChanged` events.

Comment: Here is a link to a sample application and some sample code.

The UseCase : Display an error provider against the Name Text box if a user enters data in the SurName text box, and chooses to tab out of the Name text box without entering any data.

Below is the link to a sample project, that demonstrates this.
http://sdrv.ms/YwTX1w